# Web application losing connection to Glassfish server when running in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, glassfish, icefaces

Using our web application in Internet Explorer the browser sometimes doesn’t get a response from the web server and the application eventually times out.

The application is a Java Server Faces application using the IceFaces framework.  As the user performs actions in the application, multiple AJAX requests can be issued in parallel.  This can particularly occur when the user opens multiple browser windows (views) at once.  Some AJAX requests are not returning results to the browser.

At times some of the AJAX requests can be aborted.  We believe that Internet Explorer aborts them, when a browser tab/frame is closed and there are outstanding requests.  It may be that these are requests that are using connections that were used by requests that were previously aborted, although we haven’t proven this.

When the application appears to have hung on the client (AJAX requests not returning), on the server side, stack traces for Glassfish show that threads are in NIO select calls made by Grizzly.

For example:

Stack trace from the thread pool:

```
    http-thread-pool-16093(1)" - Thread t@722
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
                at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:210)
                at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:65)
                at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:69)
                - locked <768acb28> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
                - locked <121febe5> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
                - locked <6db810ae> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
                at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:80)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.Utils.readWithTemporarySelector(Utils.java:159)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.SSLUtils.doRead(SSLUtils.java:185)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.SSLUtils.doSecureRead(SSLUtils.java:138)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.SSLUtils.doSecureRead(SSLUtils.java:101)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.InputReader.doSecureRead(InputReader.java:311)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.InputReader.doRead(InputReader.java:281)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.InputReader.read(InputReader.java:206)
                at   com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:837)
                at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:873)
                at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.end(IdentityInputFilter.java:202)
                at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalInputBuffer.endRequest(InternalInputBuffer.java:422)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.finishResponse(ProcessorTask.java:806)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.postResponse(ProcessorTask.java:782)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:758)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
                at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
                at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
                at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
                at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
                at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
                - locked <36cd6060> (a     java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
```

Looking at the network traffic using Developer Tools we see a typical pattern of requests, which includes an aborted request which Internet Explorer still shows as pending.

We haven’t seen this issue in Firefox or Chrome but we can reliably reproduce it in IE. 8,9 & 10.

Has anybody else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a little bit old, but i'll document because i lost two days researching to solve my problem because of poor documentation.

My real problem was on a desktop application (affiliate company) making infinities connections through threads without a timeout properly configured. To solve my problem I decrease my request timeout from 900 to 60 seconds.

Path on GlassFish 3.1.2.2 Admin Console: Configurations -> server-config -> network configuration -> network listeners -> http-listener-1 -> HTTP (tab) -> request timeout